# Borel sets on the plane

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let's say we have two sigma algebras $D_1$ and $D_2$ both of which contain open intervals. We know that the Borel sigma algebra $B(R)\subset D_{1}\cap D_{2}$. I'm having difficulty proving that $B(R)\otimes B(R)\subset D_{1}\otimes D_{2}$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every measurable rectangle, $A \times B$ ($A, B \in B(R)$) is in $D_1 \otimes D_2$, and since $D_1 \otimes D_2$ is a sigma algebra and $B(R) \otimes B(R)$ is the *smallest* sigma algebra containing such rectangles, the containment follows.